# Angular material broken on Galaxy S3

Tags: html, css, angular-material, samsung-galaxy

I have been trying angular material on Samsung Galaxy S3 and it looks broken. The tool bar is not showing at all and all the element are not on their place. I even tried their demo on the default S3 browser and it is broken there as well.

I have been trying to compile a Phonegap app with Angular Material and it's working fine on most of the devices but looks broken on the Galaxy S3. Sadly client is testing on that device.

Please see these screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any one has any idea what is going on ? and if there is any quick fix ?

Samsung Galaxy S5 works great

Comment: Which version of the OS/browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Gennymotion S3 emulator. The OS version 4.3.3 and its default S3 browser. Client has tested on the phone and got same result.

Comment: I'm asking because Angular Material ["is targeted for all browsers with versions n-1; where n is the current browser version"](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/README.md). Try installing using the latest version of Chrome or Firefox for Android.

Comment: It works fine on chrome on Galaxy s3. Do you think the last option is to use chromium web view instead of system web view for phonegap/cordova ? I have used that before and at this time of release I am afraid if that will be too much work ? Thanks

Comment: Well, it might be an easier solution than trying to fix Angular Material to be compatible with the stock browser. That's what I would do anyway.

Comment: I end up using crosswalk. Its a great chromium web view for hybrid applications. It solve my issue for s3. For some devices I will use this while for supported devices I will use the Default Web view. I dont think this is an answer to original problem though.